# passing parameter to javascript method

Tags: javascript

i have html code like:

```
<button type="button" class="button button-raised larger" onclick="app.shareOnIg();">Share on Instagram</button>&nbsp;
                                    </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
```

js looks like:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
shareOnIg: function () {
        Instagram.share('picture', 'example', function (err) {
                        });
    }
};
```

I want to replace example with actual value dynamically. plz advise how. I tried to add a parameter in the function and modified the call like

```
 <button type="button" class="button button-raised larger" onclick="app.shareOnIg(" + myparam + ");">Share on Instagram</button>&nbsp;
                                        </div>
```

but this did not work

Comment: I'd suggest to use `addEventListener` to bind event from JavaScript. To pass parameter from onclick, you need to wrap the string in quotes `onclick="myFun('" + param + '");`

Comment: the variable `myparam` is global ? If variable is global you can use it like that: `onclick="app.shareOnIg(myparam);"`

Comment: @Alisher Gafurov if you reply it as answer i can mark it correct

Comment: @Vik thx, i make the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case all is correct. One problem is the how is passed the variable `myparam`. If the variable is global, we can little modify the code to:

```
<button type="button" class="button button-raised larger" onclick="app.shareOnIg(myparam);">Share on Instagram</button>&nbsp;
                                </div>
```

just change:

```
 onclick="app.shareOnIg(" + myparam + ");"
```

to:

```
onclick="app.shareOnIg(myparam);"
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = {
shareOnIg: function (value) {
  console.log(value);
        Instagram.share('picture', value, function (err) {
                        });
    }
};
```

```html
 <button type="button" class="button button-raised larger" onclick="app.shareOnIg( 'This is the passed Value');">Share on Instagram</button>&nbsp;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to pass an argument to `shareOnIg` function

```
shareOnIg: function (data) {
   // console.log(data) here to see the parameter passed from the thml
   Instagram.share('picture', 'example', function (err) {});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead go unobtrusive:

```js
var app = {
  // Application Constructor
  initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
  },
  bindEvents: function() {
    var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    btns.forEach((btn)=>btn.addEventListener('click', this.shareOnIg.bind(myparam)));
  },
  shareOnIg: function(param) {
    Instagram.share('picture', 'example', function(err) {});
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```html
  <input type="text" value="John" id="name">
  
  <button onclick="sayHi('name')">Say Hi</button>
  <script>
    function sayHi(control) {
      var e = document.getElementById(control);
      console.log(e.value);
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find it much easier in the long run to dispense with `onclick` attributes and to write proper event handlers. Below is an example of how it can be done.

```
<button type="button" id="doit" … > … </button>

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function() {
    var button=document.querySelector('button#doit');
    button.addEventListener('click',function() {
        app.shareOnIg(myparam);
    }, false);
}, false);

var app = {
    // Application Constructor
        initialize: function() {
            this.bindEvents();
        },
        bindEvents: function() {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
        },
        shareOnIg: function (something) {   //  new parameter
            Instagram.share('picture', something, function (err) {

            }
        }
};
```

The solution to your question is to add a parameter variable in your `shareOnIg` method, and call the method when the tmie comes.

In the above rewrite, I have

- given the `button` an `id` to make it findable
- added some behaviour to the `DOMContentLoaded` event which triggers when the page has loaded enough for the DOM to be ready
- in the behaviour, I have located the button using its `id` and attached a function to its `click` event.